# Standard symmetric form of degree $k \geq 3$ on $\bigwedge^2 V$

Tags: representation-theory, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional (real) vector space equipped with a (real-valued) symmetric bilinear form, denoted $\langle \Bbb{u},  \Bbb{v} \rangle$ for $\Bbb{u}, \Bbb{v} \in V$. This bilinear form induces a "standard"
rank 2 symmetric tensor $\varphi_2 \in \mathrm{Sym}^2 \big( \bigwedge^2V \big)$
defined by

\begin{equation}
\varphi_2 \big((\Bbb{a} \wedge \Bbb{b}) \cdot 
(\Bbb{c} \wedge \Bbb{d})   \big)
\ := \ \det \begin{pmatrix} \langle \Bbb{a} , \Bbb{c} \rangle
& \langle \Bbb{a} , \Bbb{d} \rangle \\
\langle \Bbb{b} , \Bbb{c} \rangle &
\langle \Bbb{b} , \Bbb{d} \rangle
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

where $\Bbb{a} \wedge \Bbb{b}$ and $\Bbb{c} \wedge \Bbb{d}$ are two decomposable anti-symmetric 2-forms taken from $\bigwedge^2V$.

**Question:** For $k \geq 3$ is there a standard choice of rank $k$ symmetric
form $\varphi_k \in \mathrm{Sym}^k \big( \bigwedge^2 V \big)$
induced from the intial bilinear form $\langle \Bbb{u} , \Bbb{v} \rangle$
on $V$ ?

thanks, ines.

Comment: Indeed, the polarized Grammian determinant is a $SO(V)$-invariant element of $S^2\Lambda^r V$ for any $r$. You want the $SO(V)$-invariants of $S^k\Lambda^r V$ for more general $k$ (and maybe $r=2$ if needed).

Comment: Thanks, $\varphi_2$ is itself $\mathrm{SO}(V)$-invariant, not just its Gram determinant. Yes, I suppose I should be asking for $\mathrm{SO}(V)$-invariance for general values of $k \geq 3$.  The answer/comment given by Gjergji Zaimi to this post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23391/what-is-known-about-this-plethysm could be relevant.

Comment: I was pointing out that $\varphi_r$ **is** the (bilinearized) Gram determinant.